# Issue with Facebook app interface

Tags: facebook, redirect

I am new to Facebook development. I have a game embedded in html document in my server. I was able to get through the Oauth authorization and everything seem to be working fin.
Now after I complete all the user authorization and app authentication using Facebook PHP SDK, I am in my www.myserver.com/index.php now how do I start my game (i.e. run my html file inside IFRAME) from where I am. So to be more clear, the final piece of app authentication code is
// If User is connected to your app, then do something.
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest(); // Get the data from a signed_request token.
// Determines the access token that should be used for API calls.
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
Now at this point, how do I redirect Facebook to my html file !!
I tried 
$appurl = "mygame.html"; 
echo '';
However, I get a blank page and internet explorer gives the message

This content cannot be displayed in a frame 
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.
   What you can try: 
    Open this content in a new window

Can somebody help me please !

Answer (score 0):

Think about the flow for the authentication.

Client -> Your Canvas Page -> Your server.

Now you will know they are unauthenticated because on the 2nd step you will get an empty signed_request, it will just contain the encoding i.e. "HMACSHA256"

So at this point you, can return a HTML page that will forward the browser the OAUTH allow page.

E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
    <script>
        window.top.location = 'FacebookOauthURL';
    </script>
</html>
```

Then when they Allow you, make you specify the redirect_uri in the login url, Facebook will forward them to that URL. In most cases this will be the canvas page again e..g

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&scope=PERMISSIONS&redirect_uri=YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE
```

So when they come around again to your canvas page you will get the signed_request parameter populated with the user data.

Comment: James,Thanks for your response. I read your response several times but still confused sorry bear with me. I am going through the authentication successfully. My problem is when they come around to my canvas page for the 2nd time, I get the signed request "$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();" and access token "$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();" everything is alright at this point. However now that I am in my canvas page how do I load my html page "mygame.html" that resides in my server inside the canvas page ?

Comment: Hmm, I think the your mygame.html will need to be dynamically generated from your PHP and it's content change based on the login state of the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got this message on IE8 or less, it could be because of their implementation of [Platform for Privacy Preferences](http://www.w3.org/P3P/).

I don't understand all of it myself, as I read on [this page](http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies) :

> You can read all about the boring stuff via the link or else just
>   install the P3P Compact Policy header below. This will allow Internet
>   Explorer to accept your third-party cookie. You will need to send the
>   header on every page that sets a cookie.

To do so just add this line of code that will set the header for all your HTTP response :

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

Answer (score 0):

This restriction is because of OAuth, and most probably Facebook has implemented according to the specs, which recommends not to embed authentication flow in IFrame.
If you still want to follow the server side flow from within the canvas page, perhaps this may help
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas/